# How to share memory between userspace and kernelspace

Tags: windows, kernel, embedded, dma, userspace

I need to share memory between userspace and kernelspace. The memory is allocated in userspace and in the kernel I want to build a memory descriptor list with physical addresses to initialize a DMA controller (that resides in FPGA).

I'm using a Zynq (ARM+FPGA) with WEC2013 on it.

Microsoft gives [2 methods](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/191840), the "IOCTL method" and the "Shared Memory Object" method but I can't use either of them:

- IOCTL: because the method parameter is ignored by Windows Embedded Compact so I can't use METHOD_xxx_DIRECT. [MSDN on IOCTL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478525.aspx)
- Shared Memory Object: memory is already allocated by the user and therefore I can't create a named memory object (with CreateFileMapping). Copying the data would take too much time.

Is there another way to do this? Or can I get the MDL in userspace?

Comment: You should be able to use an IOCTL in much the same way as if you were using METHOD_NEITHER.  Just have the userspace code pass a pointer to the buffer rather than the buffer itself.  I think you would then use IoAllocateMdl() and MmProbeAndLockPages() but I'm not very familiar with kernel memory management.  [This might help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563839(v=vs.85).aspx) as it talks about doing DMA with a user buffer.

Comment: The buffer pointer is a virtual address from userspace and meaningless in kernelspace, so if there's a way to convert the pointer to a useful virtual address in kernelspace, than your  method would be OK. I would expect that it's possible, but didn't find how to do it yet.

Comment: The `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL` generated by a call to DeviceIoControl always goes to the topmost driver, so you know that `DispatchDeviceControl` is running in the context of the calling process.  So IoAllocateMdl() and MmProbeAndLockPages() should convert the virtual address into an MDL that describes the physical pages, suitable for use with MapTransfer().

Comment: Note that when an IOCTL uses `METHOD_NEITHER` the device driver receives nothing but the usermode virtual addresses for the buffers.  Windows does no pre-processing of any sort on those addresses.  So if you can find some open source or sample code using `METHOD_NEITHER`, whatever it does to access the buffer will also work in your scenario.  (Well, unless it uses functions that Windows Embedded Compact doesn't provide, I suppose.)